# MVC jQuery : Stay on same page if Validation fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application, on the search Page, I've a Search Criteria (left side) and Search Results (Right side) panes.

When a user enters the search criteria, and clicks a button I'm using JQuery Ajax, to populate the Search Results Partial View, ie. jQuery Ajax call returns HTML Partial View.

Now, if the ModelState is not valid, I would like to return the Search Criteria View Model and display the Validation Summary.
I'm not sure how to handle this scenario using jQuery Ajax.

Comment: Have you tried JQuery Unobstructive Validation with Data Annotations on Model? Reference - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: Yes, I'm making use of Data Annotations and doing client side validation. However, if the entered data doesn't meet certain criteria, there is chance of ModelState getting Not Valid on Server. I want to handle that sceneario.            If the ModelState is Valid, I return the Results Partial View, and using $('#SearchResults').html(data); I populate the div which encloses the partial View.    But, if ModelState is invalid, I want to just return the Search Criteria ViewModel and display the errors in Validation Summary.....

Comment: Then on the controller side simply make all data sanitation checks, and in case if data is not valid, then return ErrorPartialView else return SearchResults partial view. So depending on the Data Validation results, return corresponding Views.

Comment: Can you tell me what should be the best strategy, if Data Binding fails (ModelState is invalid) despite all the Data Annotations you apply and do all clent validations?  In my case, I would just like to not display the Search Results and in the Search Criteria Section display a message saying Invalid Data or something. I don't want to use another Error View or redirect to an Error page (as this is not application error)

Comment: Better criteria is to return Json result to the AJAX call, then let the caller (JQuery) decide how to show the result. So in case of error, Error Json will be returned and JQuery will show proper error message at the place of its interest. But on success call, a Search results Json will be returned and JQuery wil literate and update the view. That way your Json end point can be used on multi platforms in future. Say a mobile App wants data, then Mobile app will be least interested in html, it will be more interested in Json data. So make your controller action return JsonResult.

Comment: Thanks for the responses ramiramilu, I was actually returning JSON int the beginning but found it a bit difficult to handle on the client end for various scenarios, will look into that again, Thanks!

Comment: If you need any other information, please let me know.